# Get reference to a coroutine job in coroutine scope

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

In kotlin coroutine, most standard builder methods(such as launch) return a reference to a job,

does the design in this is to keep those reference in somethings such as a map/list(manage launched jobs "manually") or is there a way to find a launched job in a given scope ?

```
 scope.launch { /* starting a coroutine in scope */ }
```

is there a way later to get the launched coroutine reference without keeping a reference for the launched job returned by scope.launch or should we manage this ourselve(eg. keep reference returned by launch) ?

Comment: to simplify the question, is there a way to retrieve all jobs started in a coroutine scope ? is there a way to assign tag to a coroutine and later retrieve it or there is not this feature ? in case one does not want to call cancel on the entire scope but on fews coroutine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to save a reference to the parent job

```
val job = Job()
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job)
scope.launch {
    ...
    job.children // this return all jobs started in this scope
}
```

Comment: Ok good, thanks for answer, but can you for example assign a tag to a job and then find in in the children sequence ? i mean you know you have started a specific job in this scope, how you would find it back ? one way maybe would be to use the hashcode on the launched job and keep it for later use

Comment: actually i keep a global reference to the scpecific job once launched, so i can manage it individually, but maybe there is another way, maybe i could use the CoroutineContext.Key

Comment: that is the best way. The other way is by index. For example `job.children.elementAt(0)`  is the first children launched

Comment: yes i see there is not a direct/simple way to do it, and by index it's not clear to find a specific job, thanks